# how to disable ssl and use only tlsv1.2 in jboss-eap-6.4

Tags: java, web, service, jboss6.x

I am using jboss-eap-6.4 and have deployed web services, My requirement is to stop handshaking for all the client making a request to my services with ssl protocol because my application is currently deployed with tlsv1.2.

I am mentioning the standalone-full.xml configuration , jvm configuration  and jdk configuration here---

please help if i am doing anything wrong or anymore setting is needed .

1. JVM parameter-

   `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"`

   `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2"`

   `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2"`
2. standalone-full.xml parameter-

```
<ssl name="https" password="mdmitst" certificate-key-file="/local/apps/java_server/engines/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/mdmws/configuration/mdmitst.jks" protocol="TLSv1.2" verify-client="false" ca-certificate-file="/local/apps/java_server/engines/jboss/jboss-eap-6.4/mdmws/configuration/mdmwsserver.truststore" ca-certificate-password="mdmtrn"/>

</connector>
```

3. jdk configuration -(java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/security)

   `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSL,SSLv2,SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1`

After doing all these, still, my client having protocol configured SSL is able to connect my application.

Note (we have not made any hard code change in the code to allow SSL).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Additional information can be found in the [JBoss Enterprise Application Platform Administration and Configuration Guide](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/SSL_Connector_Reference1.html).